# php eclipse debugging

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, zend-debugger

I am runing a php script using eclipse. when a set breakpoint and run the script it throws me this error.

form the error it is apparent that i have change something the php.ini file. but i dont know what i have to change to make either zend or xdebug. even i dont know what the differnce b/w them.

following the error

The session could not be started.
In order to generate debug information, please make sure that the debugger is properly configured as a php.ini directive

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error also, and my issue turned out to be a misconfiguration of Eclipse. In Eclipse, I had configured (in Windows > Preferences) the "PHP Executables", but I had not configured the PHP "Debug" settings. In PHP "Debug", I had to set "PHP Debugger" to XDebug (mine was set to "Zend Debugger"). I also had to set the "PHP Executable" and toggle the "Enable CLI Debug". I wrote [a BLOG post about this](http://tech.rickumali.com/blog/2011/11/13/getting-php-debugging-xdebug-working-windows) (with some screen shots).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer this without more information about your specific setup. Xdebug has some set-up documentation [here](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/install) which may get you started.

The reference manual for xdebug's configuration settings (i.e. the lines you would want to put into your php.ini) can be found [over here](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings).

> i dont know what i have to change to make either zend or xdebug. even i dont know what the differnce b/w them.

Xdebug is a PHP extension, the zend framework is a ...well, a *framework*. They are completely unrelated. You don't have to change anything in zend-framework's configuration in order to get xdebug up and running. Your problem is just a PHP(.ini) thing.

Additional Note:
If your PHP installation is on Windows, [this page](http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php) might help you a lot. (at least it claims to show you "how to configure PHP to get Xdebug running" - I haven't tested it, I don't run Windows)

Comment: The OP probably means the zend debugger with zend. PDT supports xdebug as well as the zend debugger.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue we need to go to the windows=>preferences and type PHP. There you can find PHP Executables and add

Name: php
Executable path: path you installed PHP (ex: **C:\php\php.exe**)
PHP ini file:  C:\php\php.ini
SAPI Type: CLI
PHP debugger: Zend Debugger to Xdebug

See the screenshot below:

[image]