# error message when running a php file as php cli application in eclipse pdt

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, command-line-interface, eclipse-pdt

I am using windows 7 , and I connected the php.ini of my xampp to the php executable in the eclipse.
I also  enabled the cli debug. 
whenever I try to run the php file as a cli application I get the following message:
the session could not be started. in order to generate debug information, please make sure that debugger is properly configured as a php.ini in directive.

Comment: possible duplicate: [php eclipse debuging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487122/php-eclipse-debuging)

Comment: thanks, you're right. at first I looked there but it still didn't work but after I saw another comment it turned out that I had to change the php debugger from zend debugger to Xdebug